# PHP mailer not working for attachments?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am stucked while giving file upload path, i have a html file input name uploadfile and i am using phpmailer() to send attachement. Please help me i need php developers support. here is my code  tell me why i am getting Could not access file error. and my email is not having attachment only message is coming.

```
<div class="field">
<label for="Browse">File to upload: <span class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="inputs">
<input name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" type="file" style=" height: 37px;" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
</div>
</div>


//Form Fields
$name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $verify = isset($_POST["verify"]) ? $_POST["verify"] : "";
    $path = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
    echo $path;
    $encoding = 'base64';
    $type = 'application/octet-stream';

$objmail->From = $email;
            $objmail->FromName = $name;
            $objmail->AddAddress($toAddress, $toName);  
            $objmail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
            $objmail->Subject = $email_subject;
            $objmail->MsgHTML($email_body); 
            $objmail->AddAttachment($path,$encoding,$type);
            if(!$objmail->Send()) {
                $error = "Message sending error: ".$objmail->ErrorInfo;             
            }                   
        }
```

Comment: by looking at your code you are trying to attach the file on the fly, i thnk the better approach is that first set upload file to server and then set the attachment path also this is wrong `$path = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];` and `$objmail->AddAttachment($path,$encoding,$type);`

Comment: Can you verify the file is saved to the server?

Comment: I suggest you base your code on an up to date example that does exactly this, such as [the one that's provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Comment: Also, don't set the submitter's address as the `From` address; it will fail SPF checks and either get bounced or classified as spam. Use your own address as the from address and put the submitter's address in reply-to.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

First:

```
$path = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
$objmail->AddAttachment($path,$encoding,$type);
```

`$path` is going to be the name of the file as it was on the CLIENT machine. That has absolutely nothing to do with the temporary file that PHP stores it in, which is listed in `['tmp_name']`.

Second:

You don't validate that an upload occurred at all, and are simply assuming it succeeded. At minimum, you need to have

```
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   $objmail->AddAttachment(
       $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],  // temp location on server
       $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'],     // name that appears in email
       'base64',
       $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']   // mime type provided by uploader
   );
}
```

Comment: Friends, I am only stucked while file selection, i have form with enctype="multipart/form-data" and on its action i am posting to upload.php which is having phpmailer script. While mail is going correctly but file is not uploaded to the ftp server as file name and local file is not posted while form submit. I checked using empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) but i am not able to get the file name as it is saying file is not selected whereas i have selected the file and it is displayed in the file control in html.